# Что такое контекст в рамках TPL?

Tags: .net

Что такое контекст потока? 
Что означает фраза "переключение контекста"?

Comment: Это фишка ОС, а не .NET или тем более TPL: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Я написал в рамках TPL, что бы был понятен контекст:)